# Action bar android

Tags: android

В работе есть несколько action bar как правильнее сделать 
Для каждого отдельный xml или один изменяя его

Comment: Использовать toolbar пора уже) p.s. Как удобнее

Comment: Я его и использую

Comment: Просто у меня они разные

Comment: Мне для каждого отдельный делать или можно один как-то?

Comment: можно один, можно програмно изменять, в чем собственно проблема?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вам подсказали в комментариях, можно использовать по-разному: и так, и так.

Но с точки зрения Дзен(читай феншуй), лучше сделать для каждого ActionBar'a свой XML.